# Window buttons have suddenly changed to the right side

Tags: 12.04, unity, themes, button

I'm using updated Ubuntu 12.04 64b with unity, and im having some problems with the window managing buttons and themes. Everything was fine until this week when i rebooted the system and when it booted the upper panel of every app was wrong (default theme instead the theme that i was using, wrong font and buttons are on the right side). It only happens on windowed-mode. When i maximize the windows, theme/font gets right, and buttons are back to the left side.

I've already tried to change theme, reset unity preferences (`unity --reset`), reset compiz (`compiz --reset`), and nothing worked.

I think it is due to some package update, but i dont know which one.

Did someone had the same problem or know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed an app like Ubuntu Tweak? They have a easy option to flip buttons from one side to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this using Ubuntu Tweak>Tweaks>Windows and change from left to right or vice versa.

Comment: That worked! And i figured out what caused the problem. Ive logged in into a gnome classic session, and it changed some preferences.
Everything rockin again!! Thx!